# Font size affecting alignment

Tags: html, css

I have been experiencing trouble centering a number within a circular shaped div. The coding I have used has worked for all other elements but for some reason, one number just won't center like the rest.

I have tried to narrow the problem down and the only thing I have found is that the font size seems to be the problem. In smaller font sizes, the number centers fine, larger sizes, the number sits to the left.

Is this a bug or something someone else has experienced?

HTML:

```
<div class="circle">
    <div>4.</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#how-can-we-help-section-two .info-box-four .circle{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: green;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom:-50px;
    position:relative;
    border: 7px solid #ebeced;
}

#how-can-we-help-section-two .info-box-four .circle div{
    font-size: 35px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 90px;
}
```

Comment: I looked over your webpage and I don't see a problem (using Firefox); all the numbers look centered well enough.  Unless I take a screen shot and start counting pixels, I am not sure what to fix. Please elaborate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is `padding: 80px 40px 40px 40px;` of `.text-box`.

You can solve your problem by `position:absolute;`.

```
#how-can-we-help-section-two .info-box-four .circle div {
    font-size: 35px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 90px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because of your surrounding wrappers behaviour.
You could use an absolute positioned div or you could replace `line-height: 90px` with `width: 100%; height: 100%; display: inline-block;` on your text `div` inside `.circle`